# Issues updating firestore document by committing a batch after an async function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a cloud function that uses request-promise and cheerio to scrape a website and then check that information against a user document.

I am not entirely familiar with Javascript and Cloud Functions.

I've come so far that I managed to extract the information I need and navigate to the user's document and compare the data. Now the last piece of this function is to give the user points for each matching data point, so I need to update a map inside the user document.

This function has to loop through all users and change their document if the data point matches. I'm not sure the way I've written the code is the most optimal in terms of performance and billing if the userbase gets huge... Any pointers to how I could minimize the impact on the task would be of great help, as im new with JS.

So this is the code:

```js
exports.getV75Results = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
    let linkMap = new Map();

    const url = `https://www.example.com`
    const options = {
        uri: url,
        headers: { 'User-Agent': 'test' },
        transform: (body) => cheerio.load(body)
    }

    await rp(options)
        .then(($) => {
            for(let i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {
              //Find player from game 
              const lopp1 = $(`#mainContentHolder > div > div.mainContentStyleTrot > div > div.panel-body > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(2) > span`).text()
              const lopp1StrR1 = lopp1.replace("(", "");
              const lopp1StrR2 = lopp1StrR1.replace(")", "");
              const lopp1StrR3 = lopp1StrR2.replace(" ", "");
              linkMap.set(i, lopp1StrR3.toUpperCase());
            }
           console.log(linkMap);
           return linkMap;
        }).then(async () => {
           //Start lookup users
           let usersRef = db.collection('fantasyfotball').doc('users');

            usersRef.listCollections().then(collections => {
             collections.forEach( collection => {
               var user = collection.doc(collection.id);
               let batch = new admin.firestore().batch();
               user.get().then(function(doc) {
                 let json = doc.data();
                  //Look in users collection if players document exist
               Object.keys(json).forEach((name) => {      
 
               if(name != null) {
                 //Document with users active fotball players 
                 if(name == 'players') {
                 let i = 0;
                 Object.values(json[name]).forEach((value)  => {
                   i++;
                   if(value.localeCompare(linkMap.get(i)) == 0) {
                    
                     //Loop through user keys and find owned players if user has the correct player
                     Object.keys(json).forEach((map)  => {
                       if(map != null)
                       {
                         //Document with a map of player owned fotball players, each respective player has a key = 'fotball player' and value = '[price, points]'
                         if(map == 'ownedplayers')
                         {
                           Object.entries(json[map]).forEach((players)  => {
                             if(players[0].localeCompare(value) == 0) {
                               console.log(players[1][1]);
 
 
                               //Add points to respective player field
                               //PROBABLY NOT HOW TO CHANGE A DOCUMENT FILED, THIS DOESNT WORK..
                               players[1][1]++;
                             }
                           });
                           //EACH TIME THIS RUNS IT SAYS: "Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed"
                           batch.update(user, {'ownedplayers': json[map]});
                         }
                       }
                     });
                   }
                  });
                 }
                 } else {
                   console.log('user does not have a playermode document.');
                 }
                 });
               });
               return batch.commit().then(function () {
               console.log("Succesfully commited changes.");
               return null;
           });
         });
        });
        }).catch((err) => {
           return err;
        });
  });
```

The issues i get in the console are "Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed." and I fail to modify and add points to the player field inside the users document.

**This is the console:**
[image: Console image]

**This is the firestore document structure:**
[image: Firestore structure]

I'm completely stuck on this.. Feels like I've tried all different approaches, but I think i dont fully understand cloud functions and javascript, so i would gladly recive feedback and help on how to make this work.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Finally.... i managed to update the document successfully. I put the commit outside another ".then()". Thought I tried that, but yay I guess :P

```js
 }).then(() => {
                return batch.commit().then(function () {
                  console.log("Succesfully commited changes.");
                  return null;
               });
```

The problem now is that it commits every loop. I think the most optimal here would be to batch update **ALL** users before committing?

And again, is there a more optimal way to do this, in terms of minimizing the operation and impact? I'm afraid I go too deep with for loops instead of directly navigating to the document, but haven't found an easier way to do that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @spacecoder. There surely exists a more optimal solution here, but given the setup that you currently have, I would say that your best bet is to move the commit out of every iteration, and commit the batch only when your atomic update operations are finished. I think it also worth mentioning that [Cloud Firestore best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices) may help you with your database design and query structure if you are seeking for efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the link @sllopis, probably need to read through that to make better structure going forward! I've tried moving the commit out but then it actually go outside the loop and commit before all batches have been updated and says **"cannot commit a batch that has already been commited"** , even though i've put a .then(). for it to WAIT before going outside the loop. I'm probably not returning out of the loop correctly.

Comment: The error that you are currently receiving may be due to the fact that you are using the same `batch` object to perform several commits. This is why I was suggesting to execute multiple update operations as a single batch, and commit your batch at the very end. This [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) can help you with this task. You can go ahead and create a new `batch` object for every commit, if necessary. One thing that works for me is to start small and break things down to really understand the concepts.

Comment: @sllopis Thank you, i will try this! I'm going to try an break it down a bit. But i'll also try and create new batches, didint think that was efficient, but then i think i know how to continue further. Again, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sounds good. You're very welcome @spacecoder. Please keep me posted.